# What values do the walkback array in the SocketException contain?

Tags: java

Recently I have debugging into a problem where a connection to a database server from the application server get reset. I am pretty sure there is no reset being called from either end. But while I was debugging into the problem, while inspecting the SocketException, I found the walkback variable.

arg0 SocketException  (id=11532)
cause SocketException  (id=11532)
detailMessage "Connection reset"
stackTrace null
walkback long[50]  (id=11618)

What do the values in this variable represent?

## UPDATE

The issue was a firewall killing long running idle connections.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine it greatly depends on the database to which you are connecting. If the JDBC driver for the driver came with API docs you might look there. Also I have seen cases where Exceptions with codes like that are Error codes from the DB system (though I usually see them in SQLExceptions, not SocketException). Again I would check the documentation for the DBMS you are connecting to for a list of error codes, it may have a more useful description then your stacktrace. Finally if possible you might say which DB you are connecting to as someone with expertise related to that specific DB might have run into a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The issue was a firewall killing long running idle connections. But I was hoping to be able to use to nail down any network/communication issue if it shows up in the future.

The Application sevver was Oracle AS 10.1.3.3.1 running Java 1.5.11 on AIX.
The database server was Oracle 10g (not sure of the exact version) on AIX.